# PHP exec(node) running only for -v but not for .js file

Tags: php, node.js, exec

**Ubuntu 18 VM in AWS.**

```
$return = exec("node -v", $o, $e);
var_dump($retu);
var_dump($o);
var_dump($e);
```

**Output:**

> string(8) "v10.16.3" array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "v10.16.3" } int(0)

1. So node is installed properly.
2. exec is able to get node version.

However, `$return = exec("node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl someName", $o, $e);` is not working.

**Output:**

> string(0) "" array(0) {} int(1)

`node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl someName` is working in the terminal, the PDF file is generated and getting saved properly. **How can this issue be addressed?**

`<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` outputs as `nt authority\system`

The `var/www -R` is owned by `www-data`.

On researching some tutorials I added the following lines to sudoers file (ignoring the warnings mentioned there about the security, so that I can sudo the exec command),

[image]

`$return = exec("sudo node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl someName", $o, $e); // no difference`

The savePdf.js contains `GoogleChrome/puppeteer` code for generating PDF from URL as follows,

```
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('/var/www/mysitename/public_html/node_modules/puppeteer');
const url = process.argv[2], name = process.argv[3];

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
        {
            executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']}
        );
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.pdf({
        path: '/var/www/mysitename/public_html/resources/logs/'+name+'.pdf',
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground: true,
        margin: {
            top: "1cm",
            bottom: "1cm",
            left: "1cm",
            right: "1cm",
        }
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: In your JS. Can you use `console.log` and `try & catch` to track the run-time error?

Comment: @Banujan, thank you so much! It is fixed after adding `> /dev/null &`. However, It takes 3 to 4x times to generate the PDF when calling from exex/shell_exec compared to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `exec()` won't wait until your script complete the execution,

You need to execute following command to let `exec()` to wait,

```
 $return = exec("node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl someName  > /dev/null &", $o, $e);
```

**NOTE**

The php function **exec()** only returns the **last line of result**, while **shell_exec()** returns the **complete result**.

**Reference**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-shell_exec-vs-exec-function/

https://subinsb.com/how-to-execute-command-without-waiting-for-it-to-finish-in-php/

Comment: Okay so I changed the code as `$return = shell_exec("node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl soneName > /dev/null &");`

The $return is NULL. The PDF file is not saved.

`exec` output result as `string(0) "" array(0) {} int(0)`

Comment: In both exec and shell_exec the PDF file is not getting saved.

Comment: What output you get when executing `node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl someName` directly without php

Comment: I tried setting folder permissions for `/var/www/mysitename/public_html/resources/logs` to 777 and checked too.

Comment: The JS file will not output anything. It just accepts 2 parameters, 1st the URL, second a name. It uses Chrome in headless mode, generates the PDF of the URL and saves in a folder as name.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **[Banujan Balendrakumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8409922/banujan-balendrakumar)** for this answer.

Adding `> /dev/null &` will work in this case.

```
exec("node /var/www/savePdf.js someUrl someName > /dev/null &", $o, $e);
```

Note: There is a difference in time taken for the script to generate and save the PDF when tried from terminal and from PHP.

Comment: Great!, Good Luck!